# Weird login behaviour using Azure AD B2C with Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, azure-ad-b2c

We have a **Xamarin Forms** app that uses **Azure AD B2C** for login. I have followed this example code https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native

The **Android** version works perfectly. The workflow is seamless and works as expected.

On the **iOS** version we are getting some weird behaviour though.

Here is the flow on the **iOS** version of the app.

1. User launches the app and is presented with the Azure AD B2C login screen *(correct)*
2. User enters their credentials *(correct)*
3. The app redirects the user back to the login screen (with the username and password fields blank) *(wrong)*
4. After a few seconds the app then logs them in and navigates them to the main screen

After entering their credentials the user should be immediately navigated to the app main screen, NOT back to the login screen.

Once they are logged in, subsequently launching the app correctly logs them in. The problem is only on first login.

I can't seem to find any help on this anywhere. Is it the Safari browser, the token cache, something else? The code and workflow are correct as the **Android** version works perfectly, so it's something specific to the iOS app.

**UPDATE**
After some investigation it seems that this method may be causing the issue.

```
public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)
{
  AuthenticationContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationContinuationEventArgs(url);
  return true;
}
```

According to the docs

> this logic is meant to ensure that once the interactive portion of the
>   authentication flow is concluded, the flow goes back to MSAL

But it doesn't. It redirects the user back to the *OnAppearing*() method of the login page where it attempts (again) to acquire a token (which it does).

Is there any way to fix the behaviour of this method?

```
AuthenticationContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationContinuationEventArgs(url)
```

**UPDATE2**
Here is the login code (simplified for clarity)

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    // Check to see if we have a User in the cache already.
    try
    {
        IEnumerable<IAccount> accounts = await AuthenticationService.PCA().GetAccountsAsync();
        var account = this.GetAccountByPolicy(accounts, ApplicationConstants.SignUpSignInPolicy);
        AuthenticationResult ar = await AuthenticationService.PCA().AcquireTokenSilentAsync(ApplicationConstants.Scopes, account, ApplicationConstants.Authority, false);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Doesn't matter, we go in interactive mode
        this.OnSignIn();
    }
}

private async void OnSignIn()
{
    try
    {
        IEnumerable<IAccount> accounts = await AuthenticationService.PCA().GetAccountsAsync();
        var account = this.GetAccountByPolicy(accounts, ApplicationConstants.SignUpSignInPolicy);

        AuthenticationResult ar = await AuthenticationService.PCA().AcquireTokenAsync(ApplicationConstants.Scopes, account, App.UiParent);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        InstanceManager.LoggingHelper().TrackError(ex);
        // Checking the exception message
        // should ONLY be done for B2C
        // reset and not any other error.
        if (ex.Message.Contains("AADB2C90118"))
        {
            this.OnPasswordReset();
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert(StringConstants.ExceptionText, StringConstants.AuthenticationError, StringConstants.CloseDialog);
            this.OnSignIn();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you followed all of the tutorial?

Comment: I've cheked over the document several times. I've updated the Entitlements.plist to enable the app to work with the token cache and added the necessary code to allow the app to redirect when it's returned from Azure. If I'm missing anything please let me know.

Comment: @DomBurf Did you create a [UiParent](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/blob/master/UserDetailsClient/UserDetailsClient.iOS/AppDelegate.cs#L33) for the webview...does using the embedded webview work? Are you on a simulator or device? Which os? Have you tried to run the sample as-is...does it work? Which identity provider are you using (Facebook, Google, B2C local, etc...)?
You've probably already seen this [guidance](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Xamarin-ios-specificities#xamarin-ios-specific-considerations).

Comment: @Jenny Yes I have created a UIParent for the webview. How do I use the embedded webview? We get this behaviour on both simulators and real devices. We're using B2C accounts. I haven't tried running the sample as-is but I can give that a try.

Comment: @DomBurf Here's [general guidance on UIParent](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-tokens-interactively#controlling-the-location-of-the-dialog-with-the-parent-parameters-uiparent) . Here's how it should look for iOS:

```@CSharp
// Use only embedded webview
App.UIParent = new UIParent(true);

// Use only system browser
App.UIParent = new UIParent();
```

Comment: @Jenny I've changed the code to use the embedded web view with UIParent and this has the same problem (we've decided to keep using the embedded webview as it hides the URL which can be seen when using the system browser).

Comment: @DomBurf if you want to email me logs and share more of your code so I can try to reproduce the issue, that would be great.

Comment: @Jenny I've tried twice to email you the code to your microsoft email address, but it keeps getting bounced. I've renamed the .zip file extension to .xyz but it still bounces. Any ideas how I can get the code over to you?

Comment: @DomBurf - here's another email address ferriesj@gmail.com ...otherwise, can you push some of the code to a GitHub repo and email me the settings you use? or I can just use a sample, but would like to get as close to what you have as possible.